# CSS position header above plugin short-code

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I started a project to add a price range slider to a website. I used a plugin to create price range slider via short-code. My client prefers only to add short-code within edit page editor because he wants to use it in different pages. I used following code -

```
<center><h2><span style="color: #438bc7;">See How Much You Could Save</span></h2></center>
[realstate_pricing_calculator]
```

But it seems to be header **See How Much You Could Save** is below the pricing range slider.

I want it to be above of the slider.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: can you share this url?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

Change Your Class or other name file in this place `#sidebar`

```
#sidebar { 

  position: fixed; 
  margin-left: 410px; 
}
```